# Symfony2: You have requested a non-existent service "jms_aop.pointcut_container".

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, jms, require

I'm relatively new to symfony. I have created a symfony project, and I am trying to require JMSDiExtraBundle. The thing is that when I run the composer update command I get the following error:

```
    Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file


    [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
    You have requested a non-existent service "jms_aop.pointcut_container".



    Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



      [RuntimeException]
      An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command.



    update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]        [--no-dev] [--lock]
     [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
     [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [packagesN]



    C:\pathToProject>[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
    The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Im requiring: "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.5.0"
but I have also tried :"jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.5.*@dev"
My symfony version is : 2.6.5

Any help would be verry appreciated.

Comment: did you try this : "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master"  ?

Comment: Yes, I did. As i said below, i think that the problem was that I was already including the bundles in AppKernel when I was running the composer update command. Anyway I removed the AppKernel declarations for JMSDiExtraBundle ran composer update and then I changed the AppKernel again to include the 2 bundles(JMSDiExtraBundle and JMSAopBundle) and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. I was including the bundles in the AppKernel.php file before I had run the command: php composer.phar update.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I forgot to register the bundle "JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle" add in app\AppKernel.php:

```
new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
```